# Задача на код Хэмминга(15,11)

Tags: алгоритм, теория, перекодировка

> Вычислить вероятность ошибки информационного бита ( условно обозначим неизвестное как p_b) при коде Хэмминга (15,11), если вероятность ошибки кодового слова на входе декодера равна 10^-3 (десять в минус третей степени).

Товарищи, я не прошу готового ответа по этой задаче, мне просто нужны хоть какие-нибудь мысли касательно алгоритма решения.

PS: Вот оригинальный текст на английском, кому интересно:

(Calculate the information bit error probability pb at the error control code (15, 11) decoder output, if the error probability of code symbol at the decoder input pin = 10^ – 3.)

Comment: Надо понимать, следует рассмотреть вероятность того, что в блоке будет испорчен 1 бит, 2 бита и т.д., посмотреть, при каком количестве ошибок они все еще будут исправлены, и соответственно вычислить вероятность, что ошибки исправлены не будут - т.е. будет ошибка информационного бита.